# Did any civil resistence against the allied occupation of Japan exist?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, new-world, ww2-pacific-theater

I am looking for resistence against the allied occupation of Japan after the WWII.

What I've found:

- There were soldiers, mainly on previously by Japan-occupied areas, who went into hiding after the lost of the war, and continued guerilla fight against the countries they've settled (like [Hiroo Onoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiroo_Onoda)). Some of them didn't even know (or didn't bother on) that the war is already over.
- [Yukio Mishima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukio_Mishima) tried to initiate a coup d'etat against the now U.S.-friendly government in 1970. After he failed, he commited harakiri. But it happened far after the war.

Considering that

- many soldiers have fighted after the Japanese capitulation *in foreign countries*,
- and, there was at least one civilian taking bloody steps *in home*, but much later,

I think maybe a larger civilian resistance *in Japan*, *just after the war* should have been exist.

But I didn't find any trace of them by the (U.S.) Google.

Did they exist? At least as lonely guerilla combatants?

As far I know, the Japanese Emperor commanded the people to give up. But, I think, this commandment could have been easily challenged by saying, that the Emperor commanded it under pressure, thus it is invalid.

Comment: Relevant reading: http://www.fingleton.net/translatingjapan/ (to get a sense of how Japan works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Japanese were a rather obedient people –probable more so after the long U.S. bombing campaign.  There was the palace revolt against the Emperor which was a closer thing than generally recognized.

However, both before and after the occupation the extremist seem to have followed orders and then expressed their individual feeling by committing suicide.  In some cases, unarmed freed U.S. POWs left their camps and traveled through a largely unoccupied Japan.

Comment: I would love to see some sources in this answer.

Comment: As Machiavello wrote, a country being highly hierchized makes it a more formidable foe (it can use more of its resources in war) but makes it also easier to control once you conquer it. Anyway, sources would help show if you (and Machiavello) are right or wrong. And another possible factor was the severe hardships (bombing, lack of food, risk of being used as cannon fodder against an invasion etc.) that the Japanese civilians had to endure before the surrender.

Comment: @SJuan76: You meant Machiavell*i*, right?

Comment: Extremists committed sever political assassinations before and after the war, they are not just polite suicide minded people.

Comment: @Greg "Extremist" and "freedom fighter" are the same thing, from different viewpoints.

Comment: @ Bailey: I don't recall the title and the book has long since been loaned; but the experience of the Olympic track star Louis Zamperini captured by the Japanese after his B-24 bomber went down is generally well known and provides insight into the Japanese character.